# Getting traced route list after sending packet from source to destination

Tags: internet, route, router, traceroute, trace

So after I realized internet is just connection between routers and every routers have IP address, I want to know route of my already traversed packet.

I mean, look this example case:

Suppose my device A sending packet to another my device D through internet.

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

- A is my device with public IP 123.321.123.321
- B is stranger router that I don't know what is its IP
- C same like B.
- D is my device with public IP
  12.12.12.12

Suppose I sent simple packet, for example ping in device A.

```
ping 12.12.12.12
```

How do I know if PING packet has been routed from another router?

I expect there's simple command that will display info like this:

```
$ ping --trace 12.12.12.12
Sending packet internet gropher...
routing to (device B IP)
routing to (device C IP)
Packet arrive to (12.12.12.12) with 12ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `mtr` would do it.

`mtr google.com`, you will see outputs like this

```
                                              Packets               Pings
 Host                                      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. foo                                    0.0%    16    0.9   1.1   0.7   1.5   0.2
 2. bar                                    0.0%    16    1.3   1.0   0.5   1.4   0.3
 ...
 8. arn11s04-in-f14.1e100.net              0.0%    15   10.3  10.6  10.2  11.0   0.3
```